# The modal dialog wont show multiple data from 2 tables using codeigniter 3 & bootstrap 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, modal-dialog

i am having a problem on showing all the data in a modal which triggering by the id. the situation right now is that whenever i clicked the detail button, the modal is only show 1 row of data.
please do help me on how im gonna handle this kind of problem to show all the data from the `tbl_rekomendasi_pit` on the modal whenever i click the detail button from the table which show the data from the `tbl_kegiatan_pit`
thank you in advance!

**the tables;**

1. tbl_kegiatan_pit

| id_kegiatan | kegiatan | judul |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kesehatan | Kajian Aktual Potensi dan Pemanfaatan Tumbuhan Obat |

2. tbl_rekomendasi_pit

| id | id_kegiatan | hasil | saran |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | test | test2 |
| 2 | 1 | test3 | test4 |

**the controller;**

```
function hasil_pit()
{
$query                    = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_kegiatan_pit ORDER BY id_kegiatan");
$data['pit_kegiatan']     = $query->result();
$query1                   = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_rekomendasi_pit ORDER BY id_kegiatan");
$data['pit_rekomendasi']  = $query3->result_array();

$this->global['pageTitle'] = 'Hasil Inputan';
$this->loadViews("hasil/hasil_pit", $this->global, $data);
}
```

**the view;**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                                                       
       <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                                                
         <thead style="background-color: rgba(110, 194, 132, 0.3);">
                   <tr class="text-center">
                        <th rowspan="5" style="vertical-align: middle;">No.</th>
                            <th colspan="2" rowspan="5"class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">Kegiatan</th>
                            <th colspan="2" rowspan="5"class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">Judul</th>
                            <th rowspan="3" class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">Aksi</th>
                   </tr>
                                
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              <?php
                 $i = 0;
                 foreach($pit_kegiatan as $isi) {$i++;
                     $id = $isi->id_kegiatan;
              ?>                                 
                 <tr>
                     <td ><?=$i?></td>
                     <td colspan="2" style="text-align: middle; vertical-align: middle;"><?=$isi->kegiatan?></td>
                     <td colspan="2" style="text-align: middle; vertical-align: middle;"><?=$isi->judul?></td>                              
                     <td class="text-center"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-<?=$id?>" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
        </tbody>                                                    
     </table>
</div>
```

**the modal inside the view;**

```
            <?php
            $i=0;
            foreach($pit_rekomendasi as $isi) {$i++;
            ?>

                <div class="modal fade" id="modal-<?=$isi['id_kegiatan']?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-<?=$isi['id_kegiatan']?>" aria-hidden="true" style="overflow-y: auto;"> 
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg text-center" role="document" style="min-width: 90%;">
                        <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.699); background-color: rgba(7, 3, 3, 0.685); backdrop-filter: blur(7px); min-height: 250px; border-style: solid; border-width: 3px; border-color: rgba(0, 235, 121, 0.5);">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title text-center text-white" id="<?=$isi['id_kegiatan']?>">DETAIL REKOMENDASI</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="container-fluid mx-auto">
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">

                                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="overflow-x:auto;">
                                                    <thead style="background-color: rgba(110, 194, 132, 0.3);">
                                                        <tr class="text-center">
                                                            <th colspan="2" rowspan="5"class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">No.</th>
                                                            <th colspan="2" rowspan="5"class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">Hasil</th>
                                                            <th colspan="2" rowspan="5"class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">Saran</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><?=$i;?></td>
                                                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><?=html_entity_decode($isi['hasil']);?></td>
                                                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><?=html_entity_decode($isi['saran']);?></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you written 2 queries to getting one data. Just use joins to get data from both tables and use them together in foreach loop.

```
$data = $this->db->join('tbl_rekomendasi_pit','tbl_kegiatan_pit.id_kegiaten = tbl_kegiatan_pit.id_kegiaten')
->get('tbl_kegiatan_pit')->result_array();
```

It will result the joint result from both the table then you can iterate the result as per your requirement.

Comment: i do wrote 2 queries because the data from tbl_rekomendasi will be on the modal dialogue which gonna be the details data from the tbl_kegiatan. the tbl_kegiatan being the main table, then the tbl_rekomendasi being the describers that provide the details data.

Comment: Okay so I suggest you the idea to show the data in modal by the ajax request. Just get the data which will be open in the  listing (table), and then when you will click somewhere to open the modal, at the time get the child table data by the id to show data in modal at that time.